# How can I tell which Instagram filter was used?

Tags: effect, instagram

I want to know the name of this filter. I think it looks cool. http://instagram.com/p/vpYlx1q89e/?modal=true

It would be very nice if Instagram said what filters are used in each photo... I like to use filters a lot!

Comment: I think what looks cool is Kate Upton. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

you can actually see which instagram filter people use in they photos. Just use a [web browser for instagram](https://web.archive.org/web/20150108152113/http://square-pics.com/). That filter is called "Walden" [as you can see here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317171435/http://square-pics.com/m/858325353241497438_1085312802).

There are many other browsers, just google them.

*Edit:* By "web browser for instagram" i mean an external website designed to navigate through Instagram photos and profiles, another way to use instagram with a non-official web. Instagram.com does not allow you to have a "most popular photos" screen when you log in, plus doesn't show you the filter used in the photos, tbh, official not-mobile version of instagram is really bad and archaic. Websites designed to browse instagram like [square-pics](https://web.archive.org/web/20150108152113/http://square-pics.com/) work with Instagram's API and add aditional features (have a nicer design, shows filters used, popular photos and users, a nicer view **and** preview of the photos, possibility to see comments, likes and descriptions without having to enter to photos...) that you can't find in the official Instagram website for PC.

That's the reason why you can find a lot of this kind of websites.

Comment: square-pics is down : http://downoruprightnow.com/status/square-pics.com